# How to make a code exclude a word in a list of numbers

Tags: python

So I've been working on the code and I have made a lot of progress but the one thing that keeps on happening is now whenever I put in one number the code stops. What have I done wrong in the code for it to stop after one input?

```
largest = None
smallest = None
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num != type(int):
        print("Invalid input")
        break
try:
    num = int(num)
except:
   if num != (type(int)):
        print("Invalid input")
        
if largest is None:
    largest = num
elif num > largest:
    largest = num
        
if smallest is None:
    smallest = num
elif num < smallest:
    smallest = num

print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

Comment: you need a `try: ... except ValueError:` around `fnum = float(num)` because ` fnum = float('applejuice')` will crash your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have indentation error as well as comparison errors along with float type cast error for str!

I have re-written most of your code!

Let me know if you have specific questions!

```
largest = float('-inf')
smallest = float('inf')
while True:
    num = input("Enter a number: ")
    if num.lower() == "done" : break
    print(num)
    try:
        fnum = float(num)
    except Exception as exp:
        print(f"Invalid Input, Error: {exp}")
    largest = max(largest, fnum)
    smallest = min(smallest, fnum)
    
    
print("Maximum is", largest)
print("Minimum is", smallest)
```

```
Enter a number: 1
1
Enter a number: What is this?
What is this?
Invalid Input, Error: could not convert string to float: 'What is this?'
Enter a number: -10
-10
Enter a number: 100
100
Enter a number: Done
Maximum is 100.0
Minimum is -10.0
```